# YouTube analytics api total views off for large channels?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Analytics API to retrieve total views for channels.  For small channels the total views match the number visible on the about tab of the channel.  On larger channels there's a huge difference.  For example one channel is reporting 1.6 billion via analytics api where the public page is reporting 490 million.  Why is there a difference?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2010-01-01&end-date=2014-10-03&metrics=views%2Ccomments%2CfavoritesAdded%2Clikes%2Cdislikes%2CestimatedMinutesWatched%2CaverageViewDuration&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be the difference is between **public** and private **view**.

If a video has lot of views but public cannot see her, YouTube doesn't count this view in public.( counter like about page.)
YouTube Analytics count this private view.

> we'll remove view counts from unlisted and private videos so the view
>   count shown for a channel will include only the views from public
>   videos. If you have private or unlisted videos that you want to count
>   towards your channel's view count, you can simply set them to "public"
>   and they will be included in your view count within a day.

[source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtubepartners/Wo5_pGAV-Nk/uahfAQLlGmoJ)

Comment: I suspected something like this.  Is there a way to have the analytics api return only public videos views for the totals?